# Django example for a web app that show git logs

Tags: django

I am looking for an example about how to display git log data about a commit.

I get the commit via shell script; then retrieve the info about this commit and make it pretty. Now I would like to add on a web app in Django, the capability to pass hash and project repo name, so I can display thee info in a nice way.

Altho I can't find tutorial that show how to build a web app for django, that display a page in this way. I just start with the tutorials today, so I don't know much. I also need to read from file, so I don't need a database nor the model, right?

IS this too complicate for a first Django app?

Comment: Are you planning to save the log into db or print the way itself

Comment: Most likely I won't save the log, the idea is to get a request only when needed; so if someone wants to pass a specific entry for a repository, they will see the data related to the commit, the diff and once done; close the page and forget about it. Would be convenient maybe to save it, if someone else search that specific commit, but chances are that is quicker to just retrieve and display the page again.

Comment: This question is too broad for us to answer properly. I would suggest to start with running through the tutorials on http://www.djangoproject.com/ and then move on from that. Reading from file and talking to a git repo / github is fairly straight forward from that. There are libraries that helps you with the communication.